# Keep x files in a directory and remove any older files

Tags: bash

This is the command to remove anything more than x files from within  a directory

```
(ls -t|head -n 5;ls)|sort|uniq -u|xargs rm
```

I would like to how to modify this to do the same from outside the directory using command line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using find to keep only the x newest files:

```
find /path/to/dir ! -newer $(ls -t | sed 'x!d') -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
cd /path/to/dir && { (ls -t|head -n 5;ls)|sort|uniq -u|xargs rm; }
```

In case of non-existing directory, it will do nothing.

Comment: I would like to do it via a script . A question i have is if I use your suggestion does the script now assume that it lives in /path/to/dir? .

Comment: @highriser: no, you can save this line into a script and put the script elsewhere. Then call the script from where you want, with the path-to-dir as an argument. Note that, in that case, you need to modify the line like this: `cd "$1" && { (ls -t|head -n 5;ls)|sort|uniq -u|xargs rm; }` if you really want the script take the argument into account. You may also first check if `$1` is provided.

Answer (score 2):

for your original line I would suggest that you can reverse the sort and use head to exclude the last lines.  It then becomes:

```
ls -drt ~/somedir/* | head -n-5 | xargs rm
```

I would encourae you to investigate the find command for problems like this.  You gain more control and you could handle things like ties (e.g. remove files older than the fifth oldest)

There are unanswered details like:

- I assume you want to exclude subdirs in timechecks
- I also guess from the use of `ls` that you want non-recursive
- Don't know what you want do to about hidden files

You get the idea.  The man page for find has examples but something like:

```
DIR=cdplatform && find $DIR -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -newer $(ls -Fdrt ${DIR}/* | grep -v "/$" | head -n-4 | tail -1) -exec rm {} \;
```